# data query with angularjs and firebase3

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm getting started with Firebase 3 and am confused as to how to do some queries of the database.

Essentially, I have an example dataset as in the following:

```
{
  "people":[
{
  "name": "fred smith",
  "gender": "male",
  "age": 30,
  "images":
  {
    "image_main": "images/image1_main.jpg",
    "image_thumb": "images/image1_th.jpg"
  }
},
{
  "name": "mary hairy",
  "gender": "female",
  "age": 25,
  "images":
  {
    "image_main": "images/image2_main.jpg",
    "image_thumb": "images/image2 _th.jpg"
  }

}
 ]
}
```

And the app is set up as the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

//set up the firebase config
var config = {
  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "project-XXX.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://project-XXX.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "project-XXX.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

}]);
```

So, I have imported the json dataset into firebase and it is set up appropriately.

The controller for this is:

```
myApp.controller("PeopleController", 
 ["$scope", "$firebaseArray",          function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
 var ref = firebase.database().ref('people');

 var people= $firebaseArray(ref);

 $scope.people = people;
 console.log($scope.people);
```

OK, so far so good. I can get the people and in the html the ng-repeat loops through the people object as required.

Now, how do I get the reference to the images. I would like to be able to grab each person and display the image_main and the image_thumb but can not work out how to do this.

Thanks